# jquery wrap a e-mail address

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have several e-mail addresses in a text, which is saved in a variable.
the e-mail addresses are in this format `test[-@-]test.com`.

Now I want to wrap each e-mail adress with a span element `<span>test[-@-]test.com</span>`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your text is in a variable string, you can just use regular expressions:

```
str = str.replace(/([a-z]+\[-@-\][a-z]+\.[a-z]+)/g,'<span>$1</span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yjVFj/

Mind you, though, that [matching email addresses with regular expressions can be tricky business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses).

Answer (score 1):

Much better to use a callback function:

```
var wrap = function(text) {  
    $("#Text").html( function(){  
        var patt1= new RegExp(text, "g");  
        return $("#Text").html().replace(patt1, function(match){return "<strong>"+ match +"</strong>"});  
    });  
};
```

As on http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml#replacecallback

Answer (score 0):

Use to create a new span element like so:

```
var emailArray = ["test1[-@-]test.com", "test2[-@-]test.com", "test3[-@-]test.com"];
$.each(emailArray, function (index) {
    emailArray[index] = $('<span>' + emailArray[index] + '</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For plain-old vanilla JavaScript:

```
function wrap(text, element) {
    return document.createElement(element).innerText(text);
}
```

Otherwise, if you're using jQuery, `.wrap('span')` ([jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/))